# How does sudo remember you already entered root's password?

Tags: linux, sudo

When using sudo on Linux, it asks for root password, but only the first time you run it. If you run another sudo command, it remember you already entered the password previously and doesn't ask for it:

```
thomas@ubuntu:~$ sudo id
[sudo] password for thomas: ******
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
thomas@ubuntu:~$ sudo id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

How does sudo do it? Where is this information stored? My idea is that it remembers the terminal id (like pts/1), but where is this stored? The first sudo process is ended when it's done with the command, right?

I know sudo is a setuid program, so it has root's privileges all the time, but I still can't think of a good place to store an information that a user has already entered a password. Is there some daemon process involved?

Comment: There's a pretty good overview of how sudo works here: http://aplawrence.com/Basics/sudo.html It details sudo's behavior with remembering passwords (e.g. the default timeout is 5 minutes), although it does not cover the specifics of _how_ sudo remembers the password. Still interesting, though.

Comment: Just a tiny correction, sudo asks you for *your* password, not root's password

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Where is this information stored?

It's probably under `/var/db/sudo` or `/var/run/sudo` and you'll probably find directories of usernames with files under them ordered by tty number.

The actual privileges granted, including how long the sessions lasts before you have to enter your password again depends on how sudoers is setup. There's settings to grant/restrict a lot of different things, but those aren't stored in these files which only store timestamps. How long a session lasts, or when sudo needs to prompt for your password again, is determined by a delta of current time and the session timestamp in this directory, and how long sudo is setup to allow a session to last.

Comment: As to how long, from [ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo): "When using sudo, your password is stored by default for 15 minutes."

Answer (score 12):

Try `man sudo` and have a look at the FILES section:

> /var/lib/sudo           Directory containing time stamps

And at the `SECURITY NOTES`

> sudo will check the ownership of its time stamp directory (/var/lib/sudo by default) [...]

(man pages from Debian 6.0.4)